# Next.js serverless function runs on local machine but not when deployed to Vercel

Tags: node.js, next.js, environment-variables, aws-serverless, vercel

I am trying to make a simple question-answering bot powered by OPEN AI's GPT-3 and for this, I am using the open-ai API npm package. I am using Next.js for making this. The app is running perfectly fine on my local machine but does not run when deployed to Vercel.

Here is the link to Vercel deployed app - [Link](https://question-answering-bot-gpt-3.vercel.app/)

I have set up environment variables in Vercel but still, it's not working.

Here is the link to the GitHub repository, please check pages/api/open-ai.js - [Link](https://github.com/SahilAujla/Question-Answering-Bot-GPT-3)

Here is the open-ai.js file:

```
function handler(req, res) {
  const OpenAI = require("openai-api");
  const OPENAI_API_KEY = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;

  console.log(OPENAI_API_KEY);

  const openai = new OpenAI(OPENAI_API_KEY);

  const prompt = req.body.message.trim();

  console.log(prompt);

  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      (async () => {
        const gptResponse = await openai.answers({
          documents: [],
          question: `${prompt}`,
          search_model: "ada",
          model: "ada",
          examples_context: "",
          examples: [
            [
              "What is human life expectancy in the United States?",
              "78 years.",
            ],
          ],
          max_tokens: 64,
          stop: ["\n", "<|endoftext|>", "."],
        });

        console.log(gptResponse.data.answers[0]);

        res.status(200).json({ answer: gptResponse.data.answers[0] });
      })();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(err.status);
      console.log(err.status());

      res.status(500).json({ answer: err.status });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(500);
  }
}

export default handler;
```

Comment: What is the 500 error telling you? Have you looked at the realtime logs? https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/logs

Comment: Hey Lee, Yes, the issue is resolved. Actually, I have to take permission from OpenAI before publishing the app to production. They block all the requests coming from domains other than localhost:3000 and the ones whitelisted by them. The code overall is correct.

Comment: Got it - have you reached out then about adding your production domain to be allowed?

Comment: Yes, I have, they said that they would respond in under 7 days, let's see.